# Getting rid of too many if's. What's the better approach?

Tags: java, if-statement

My issue is related to design currently. I am having a jsf parameter page and it submits 
different parameters to generate a jasper report. E.g. Nationality, Travel type, Visa type,
Gender and so on. Parameters can be a combination. E.g. At one time user can select 
nationality and visatype and leave others blank which will make other's default to the value
of ALL. I submit the id's from the parameter page. If nothing was selected by the user i am
setting the values manually to ALL in the setter methods. Here is a snapshot of my managed
bean method and the POJO.

```
private ReportBean generateReportBean(TravelDetailSearchParams searchParams, String reportPath){
    TravelDetailReportBean travelDetailReportBean = new TravelDetailReportBean();
    if(searchParams.getGender().getId() != 0){
      for(Lookup lookup : gender){
          if(lookup.getId() == searchParams.getGender().getId()){
            travelDetailReportBean.setGender(lookup.getDescEnglish());
            break ;
          }
      }
    }
    else{
      travelDetailReportBean.setGender(searchParams.getGender().getDescEnglish());
    }

    if(searchParams.getTravelType().getId() != 0){
      for(Lookup lookup : travelType){
        if(lookup.getId() == searchParams.getTravelType().getId()){
          travelDetailReportBean.setTravelType(lookup.getDescEnglish());
          break ;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      travelDetailReportBean.setTravelType(searchParams.getTravelType().getDescEnglish());
    }

    if(searchParams.getPort().getId() != 0){
      for(Lookup lookup : port){
        if(lookup.getId() == searchParams.getPort().getId()){
          travelDetailReportBean.setPort(lookup.getDescEnglish());
          break ;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      travelDetailReportBean.setPort(searchParams.getPort().getDescEnglish());
    }

    if(searchParams.getNationality().getId() != 0){
      for(Lookup lookup : country){
        if(lookup.getId() == searchParams.getNationality().getId()){
          travelDetailReportBean.setCountry(lookup.getDescEnglish());
          break ;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      travelDetailReportBean.setCountry(searchParams.getNationality().getDescEnglish());
    }
    if(searchParams.getVisaType().getId() != 0){
      for(Lookup lookup : visaType){
        if(lookup.getId() == searchParams.getVisaType().getId()){
          travelDetailReportBean.setVisaType(lookup.getDescEnglish());
          break ;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      travelDetailReportBean.setVisaType(searchParams.getVisaType().getDescEnglish());
    }
    logger.debug("nationality: " + travelDetailReportBean.getCountry());
    logger.debug("travelType: " + travelDetailReportBean.getTravelType());
    logger.debug("visatype: " + travelDetailReportBean.getVisaType());
    logger.debug("port: " + travelDetailReportBean.getPort());
    travelDetailReportBean.setReportName(BorderEntryExitConstants.TRAVEL_DETAIL_REPORT_NAME);
    travelDetailReportBean.setReportPath(reportPath);
    return travelDetailReportBean ;
  }
```

The POJO code is shown below

```
public class TravelDetailReportBean extends ConcreteReportBean {
  private String gender ;
  private String travelType ;
  private String port ;
  private String country ;
  private String visaType;

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void setGender(String gender) {
    if(gender == null || gender.equals("")){
      this.gender="ALL";
    }
    else{
    this.gender = gender;
    }
  }

  public String getTravelType() {
    return travelType;
  }

  public void setTravelType(String travelType) {
    if(travelType == null || travelType.equals("")){
      this.travelType ="ALL";
    }
    else{
    this.travelType = travelType;
    }
  }

  public String getPort() {
    return port;
  }

  public void setPort(String port) {
    if(port == null || port.equals("")){
      this.port ="ALL";
    }
    else{
      this.port = port;
    }
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    if(country == null || country.equals("")){
      this.country ="ALL";
    }
    else{
    this.country = country;
    }
  }

  public String getVisaType() {
    return visaType;
  }

  public void setVisaType(String visaType) {
    if(visaType == null || visaType.equals("")){
      this.visaType ="ALL";
    }
    else{
    this.visaType = visaType;
    }
  }
}
```

Issue is the generateReportBean method. i am putting to many if's to see if the id is not
zero get the description of that id from lookup else just set it like that and inside bean
setter i am checking for null. If null setting it to ALL.

My issue is currently i have few parameters and these if's can work for a while but what
if the search parameter grow. THe if's will look ugly. Can someone suggest me a better approach
to get rid of these if's.
Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

If `Lookup` is List of objects then you can provide equals method based on `id` and then you can directly do

```
if(lookup.contains(searchParams.getTravelType()))
{
 //code here
}
```

Comment: Amit thanks. I was looking forward to know logically when we call the contains method, does it call the equals() method implicitly?

Comment: Yes but as Integers has equals method implemented properly List<Integer> contains method will always work for List<Integers>

Comment: Amit lookup is a list of objects. That object can be of any type like e.g. VisaType , Country and so on. Is that so peter? That is what i can get from your code that your list of storing some kind of objects.

Comment: @Ben,@Peter the idea remains same If you override equals in object which is inside `Lookup` then you can always use `contains` no additional checks are needed

Comment: @AmitD you are correct. I was pointing to same. Hopefully peter that resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Chain of Responsibility design pattern.

- This will increase the code readability and maintainability
- Reduces the number of "if" loops

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Divide the parsing pieces into different functions. eg.

```
checkgender(searchParams.getGender(), travelDetailReportBean);
```

or

```
travelDetailReportBean.setGender(checkgender(searchParams.getGender()));
```

Depends on how you want it

Comment: Thanks Minion for your prompt answer. But should i put these check conditions separate from the managedbean as the logic deasn't belong here. But it means that as number of parameters will grow, it will also grow a number of methods. Aint it?

Comment: Depends on how you want it again. I would probably place them in the same object with the generateReportBean or as mentioned above in a utility class

Comment: Thanks Minion, it makes more sense to me. I would probably place them in the same object.

Comment: :) Minion. I don't have a privilage to upvote as i have feedback score of 14. I can only upvote if my reputation is 15. :) You need to increase my feedback score maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put these methods into a utility class and do as Minion has suggested.

```
travelDetailReportBean.setGender(ParamUtil.checkGender(searchParams.getGender());
```

Putting validation condition in a dto as you have done is not a smart coding move. Is it a generic
parameter screen you are trying to make? Mostly, every report should have a separate parameter
screen if every report parameters differ.
HTH,
Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben.It makes sense to me now. Yes it is a generic screen.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO testing for empty/null Strings is too common to code it manually. I like to use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from [Apache Commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/lang/) to simplify it. Combined with Java's `?` operator, you can write it much clearer:

```
private static final String OPTION_ALL = "ALL";

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = StringUtils.isEmpty(gender) ? OPTION_ALL : gender;
}
```

Of course, if you have a large number of fields a generic approach may be justified.

**EDIT: Conceptual consideration**

As I see, you perform value checking in the classes setter methods. I would advise against doing so: I expect setters to *only* assign a value to an instance variable. If they do more, this might lead to confusion. You are probably using the class to parametrize some search function, so a better place for ensuring non-empty member values would be right before performing that search.

Comment: Wow. That was a fab answer puras. Can we use Apache POI as well or only apache commons lang?

Comment: Thanks! Apache POI is a completely different project containing MS Office tools. Commons instead has many basic components which I find helpful in any Java environment.

Comment: Thanks Puras. I got the commons lang library. But for getting a gender description against a particular id e.g. still i need to put an if check check whether it was zero or some valid value and iterate through the list.

Comment: I have updated the code to break down into different methods and gotten rid of if checks in my bean. Thankyou puras. it has improved my code a little :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also annotate the fields that you need to do a lookup and then use a single loop to see their values in searchParams  and if id is present, do a lookup.